# How to add string ranges in flutter line chart X-axis?

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, flutter-packages

I am using charts_flutter package for line charts. I have to add some string ranges in X-axis, 0-1200,1200-3200,etc.How can I add this?

Answer (score 0):

Here you found the documentation for this plugin

https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/gallery.html